# Reminders on shared calendar events don't propagate to the people accessing it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I created the events with the email remainder in the google calender and added guests to it to have them to receive the reminders also.

But it sends the reminder to me only and not to the others.

After I have searched for solution I have found a discussion [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/calendar/importing-and-exporting/svOe_Ujv3SE). In which I came to know that this feature is not available as of now. But so many peoples are asking the feature to be implement.

Still no solutions from people in google. I hope google will support for this feature.

I want to send reminders/notify to a SPECIFIC Member of my CALENDAR A using GAS, to whom I shared with:

CAL A = Owner (myself)
Other members in CAL A  = M1,M2,M3

When I create an event , followed by setting a addEmailreminder() and addSmsreminder() using GAS to the CAL A, I want the SPECIFIC member 'M1' ONLY to receive  the  EMAIL reminder & oly fr this PARTICULAR event & not by default fr all events & fr all members.

Hw to achieve this?

**Restrictions:**

1. I dont want all members by default to get the NOTIFICATIONS.
2. I dont want to  set REMINDER fr all EVENTS in the SETTINGS PAGE, I need oly particular EVENTS to get reminder.
3. I dont want INVITE/GUEST concept.

I want to implement this in my GAS coding. Is there any workaround to achieve this or Is there any direct way to achieve this which I may missed when I searched for.?

So Pls guide me to achieve this sending remainder for the particular persons for the particular events to be create in the particular calender.

Tnx,
CL.

Answer (score 1):

Not being able to set reminders for other users, without their permission, is the expected behavior.

If you want send or setup custom reminders for guests, you have a couple of options within Apps Script that I know of:

1. Create your own web app that runs as the user where the guest has to go to and authorize the Calendar service to create the event and reminders on their behalf.
2. Create your own email reminders that a script of yours sends out to the guests automatically like the real GCal reminders do.