# How do you automatically send a message to guests in a calendar invite?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Apps Script to automate certain workflows. Whilst I can manually email guests in a calendar invite I've sent out, I'm struggling to find a way to write code that allows me to do this. The email must contain the google calendar invite, just as using the 'email guests' feature manually does.

When I struggled to find an inbuilt CalendarApp function that allows me to do this, I tried using Gmail's SendEmail function, however I cannot find a way to attach the google calendar invite details.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```html
function sendMatchReminders() {

  var today = new Date(),
      tomorrow = new Date(),
      i = 0,
      emails;
      
  tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+2);
      
  var events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("MY_EMAIL").getEventsForDay(tomorrow, {search: 'vs'});
   
  for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
  
    emails = events[i];
   
  }
     
      
}
```

Comment: When creating an event, you can add a parameter [**`addEmailReminder(minutesBefore)`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#addEmailReminder(Integer)), this will send an email reminder to the event. You also provide a **`addSmsReminder(minutesBefore)`** or **`addPopupReminder(minutesBefore)`** and do take note that the value must be at least 5 minutes, and at most 4 weeks (40320 minutes), before the event. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot but that just sends me a reminder and not my guests.

Comment: If that is the case, you can set a custom reminder by getting the list of attendees of the event then sending an email to each. (Just like a normal reminder do)

Comment: Just like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/17387534/5995040

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea to include your script..

It is possible using the options parameter in the create method.

It's in the Google Calendar Reference [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent(String,Date,Date,Object)). These options are passed as a javascript object so a basic example using the createEvent method:

```
 var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent('Apollo 11 Landing',
 new Date('July 20, 1969 20:00:00 UTC'),
 new Date('July 20, 1969 21:00:00 UTC'),
 {sendInvites: true});
```

This is an example copied from the above and modified. I haven't tested it tho.

Comment: Thanks have added the script. Realised my question might be slightly misleading. I've already sent a calendar invite. I now want to send an email reminder. The way I would manually do this is to use the 'email guests' feature in google calendar. But I cannot find a way to replicate this in apps script. Your suggestion creates a new calendar event which I do not intend to do. Thanks!